# Uploadify not running server side script at all

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

So I'm initialising uploadify with the most basic settings and I have tried this when this code is the only javascript in my scripts file, and I'm getting no errors.

```
$('#FAbtn').uploadify({
    'swf' : '/assets/swf/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : '/assets/php/uploadify.php'
});
```

When uploading an image for instance, I get the upload success drop down beneath the button, but uploadify.php is not being contacted at all. (the directory path is correct, as soon as I give it a wrong file like uploadify2 then it gives a 404). Even if the uploadify.php script has a 1 line var_dump, nothing happens. Have looked in Charles and it's not being contacted.

Putting 'onSelect' in works fine to alert the file select popup box so I'm sure the javascript is running fine.

Any thoughts? I'm on localhost by the way.

Comment: Try to check file exists in your specified upload directory and also check with onComplete function get your file name like 'onComplete' : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
      var fName = fileObj.name;
      alert(fName);
    }